# How to get a text in a div class inside an iframe with no id?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a tampermonkey script that extract a website from the following html page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://some-url.com/ll" title="test" name="ws_block" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px; width:100%; height: 320px;">
            <html>
                <head>
                        <!-- A particular character set can be specified by assigning "charset" -->
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                    <title>Title</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/en/Custom/blockStyle.css" type="text/css">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="wrapper">           
                        <div id="logo"><img src="/banner.gif" alt="[ORG]" border="0"></div>
                        <div class="block-body">
                            <div class="textLine">
                                <div class="ws-label label" data-strid="url"><script> ws.print("url"); </script>Address:</div>
                                <div class="text">https://www.my_website.com/</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="textLine">
                                <div class="ws-label label" data-strid="category"><script> ws.print("category"); </script>Category:</div>
                                <div class="text">My-Website</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to extract my website link: 
https://www.my_website.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window` object has a `frames` array with all the iframes contained in your page, so you can iterate it and try to get your content.

If you only have an iframe then `window.frames[0].getElementsByClassName(classname)` will do the trick.

Please have a look at its documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

Comment: I was able to find the document using chrome console but not with tampermonkey

Comment: turns out I needed a delay to extract the document from the iframe as it was still being loaded.

Comment: You may be able to listen to the document ready event of it. Try with `window.onload` I mean `window.frames[0].onload` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access into other origin (domain) iframes by javascript for security reasons!

You should do it by server side languages like php!

if the domain and iframes src are in one origin you can use like [r1verside's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45803737/7580839):

```
window.frames[0].getElementsByClassName(classname)
```

Comment: That's wrong. You can access if both the main document and the iframed one belong to the same domain.

Comment: he has entered the iframe url and his own websites url in the question bro @r1verside

Comment: That's an assumption. Please rephrase your answer.

Comment: i edited my answer, thanks for your care! @r1verside

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different methods to find an element in the DOM that don't involve using their ID.

You need to find some other identifying feature of the element and use that.

For example:

```
document.querySelector("iframe");
```

… will return the *first* iframe in the document.

---

After that, you would use exactly the same method as you would use if you had got the iframe by the id.